# How to use continue in angularjs with correct index value

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use continue in ng-repeat in agularjs. It worked fine but the  problem is if one condition is satisfied the index value also changed, that is the order of index also changed.
my Code is given below.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="appointment in rows" ng-if="appointment.isBrightFuture==1">
    <td ng-class="{{appointment.isBrightFuture==1?'tdImage':''}}">{{$index+1}}
      <img ng-if="appointment.isBrightFuture==1" ng-src="img/brightfuture_logomedium.png">
    </td>
    <td>{{appointment.date}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.time}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.specialtyId=="5"?'Pediatrics':appointment.specialty}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.physicianName}}
      <br/>{{appointment.orgName}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.reason!="null"?appointment.reason:''}}</td>
    <td>
      <img ng-if="hasAppointmentPrivilege()" src="img/edit.png" ng-click="editPastAppointment($index)" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img ng-if="hasAppointmentPrivilege()" src="img/cancel.png" ng-click="deletePastAppointment($index)" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you expect the picture to look like?

Comment: i want with correct order with 1,2,3

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ng-if to avoid displaying one of the rows, you should filter the array before displaying it. The problem with that is the inverse of the one you have, though: $index will be the index of the current element in the filtered array, and not in the original array. So you should refactor the functions to accept the element itself rather than its index:

```
<tr ng-repeat="appointment in rows | filter:hasBrightFuture">
    <td class="tdImage">{{$index+1}}
      <img src="img/brightfuture_logomedium.png" />
    </td>
    <td>{{appointment.date}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.time}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.specialtyId=="5"?'Pediatrics':appointment.specialty}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.physicianName}}
      <br/>{{appointment.orgName}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.reason!="null"?appointment.reason:''}}</td>
    <td>
      <img ng-if="hasAppointmentPrivilege()" src="img/edit.png" ng-click="editPastAppointment(appointment)" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img ng-if="hasAppointmentPrivilege()" src="img/cancel.png" ng-click="deletePastAppointment(appointment)" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.hasBrightFuture = function(appointment) {
    return appointment.isBrightFuture === 1;
}
```